# concatenate String with Int in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I need to dynamically loop through column names and fetch the records.

Below is my table, and I am using SQL Server 2017.

```
-- DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

-- WHILE @cnt < 3
-- BEGIN
--     SELECT 'Name' + @cnt FROM Emp
--     SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
-- END;
--GO
```

but this query is not working.

How to loop through columns such as `Name+@cnt`?

Expected output:

```
User1
User2
User3
```

`Emp` table:

[image]

Comment: Fix your data, so the different column groups are in different rows.

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL and build the select that way  but I think it is more of an issue the way it is designed, should have a lookup table for each different name/address number

Comment: The table structure is strange. Presumably there's more than 1 record in the input table? Are you expecting the output to be a single row of text per input record, comprising the three names?

Comment: @JohnRC   yes its weird, problem is i should go with this table. I am expecting a record per row.

Comment: You'll need [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to use variables for your object names (tables, columns, databases).  I would agree with @GordonLinoff that your schema isn't so great which has lead you to this rather complex solution.

Comment: I agree with the points above; and to give you a pointer to what people are referring to, it's called [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization); but you may find that article's a bit hard to digest, so here's an [introduction to normalisation from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt < 4
BEGIN
   SET @statement = @statement + ' select Name' + CAST(@cnt AS VARCHAR) + ' from Emp;'
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL would be best fit for this task:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000) = '';
select @sql = @sql + ' select ' + name + ' from MYDATABASE.dbo.Emp ' from MYDATABASE.sys.columns
where name like 'Name[1-3]'

exec(@sql)
```

The query will search for column names like `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3` and construct three `SELECT` queries, which then will be executed by `EXEC` function.

**NOTE:** I assumed that table is in `dbo` schema and you need to use your database instead of `MYDATABASE`.